# EXC_BAD_ACCESS trying to to implement NSTableView delegate protocol

Tags: objective-c, delegates, exc-bad-access

I am following the example of "Cocoa programming for Mac OS X", which explains how to implement the protocol for NSTableView.
I have tried to do everything like the book says, but probably I have missed something.
There is a NSSpeechSynthesizer and a text field, every time the user presses the button "speak", the content of the text field is spoken by the speech synthesizer.There is also a NSTableView containing the list of all voices, the user can select the voice that he likes more.
This is the code:

Interface:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface SpeakLineAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource> 
{
@private
    NSWindow *window;
    NSTextField *textField;
    NSTableView *tableView;
    NSButton *speakButton;
    NSSpeechSynthesizer* ss;
    NSButtonCell *stopButton;
    NSArray* voices;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSButton *speakButton;

- (IBAction)speak:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSButtonCell *stopButton;


@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "SpeakLineAppDelegate.h"

@implementation SpeakLineAppDelegate
@synthesize stopButton;
@synthesize textField;
@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize speakButton;

@synthesize window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
 }


- (id) init
{
    self=[super init];
    if(self)
    {
        NSLog(@"init method called");
        ss=[[NSSpeechSynthesizer alloc]initWithVoice:nil];
        [ss setDelegate: self];
        voices=[NSSpeechSynthesizer availableVoices];
    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)speak:(id)sender 
{
    NSString* str=[textField stringValue];
    if([str length]>0)
    {
        [ss startSpeakingString: str];
        [stopButton setEnabled: YES];
        [speakButton setEnabled: NO];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"The string has length zero");
    }
}

- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender 
{
    [ss stopSpeaking];
}

- (void) speechSynthesizer:(NSSpeechSynthesizer *)sender didFinishSpeaking:   (BOOL)finishedSpeaking
{
    NSLog(@"Has finished speaking");
    [stopButton setEnabled: NO];
    [speakButton setEnabled: YES];
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return [voices count];
}

- (id) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSString* str=[voices objectAtIndex: row];
    NSDictionary* dict=[NSSpeechSynthesizer attributesForVoice: str];
    return [dict objectForKey: NSVoiceName];
}


- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSInteger row=[tableView selectedRow];
    if(row!=-1)
    {
        NSString* str=[voices objectAtIndex: row];
        [ss setVoice: str];
        NSLog(@"New voice: %@",str);
    }
}

@end
```

I also have done the following in the xib file:
-I have linked the NSTableView's options "data source" and "delegate" to SpeakLineAppDelegate (the filename of my application).
The IBOutlet textField is linked with the NSTextField in the xib file, also speak and stop are the action set for the buttons n the xib file.
The NSTableView is the IBOutlet "tableView", also this one is linked in the xib file.
The problem: I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS at this point:

```
- (id) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSString* str=[voices objectAtIndex: row];  // here I get the exception
    NSDictionary* dict=[NSSpeechSynthesizer attributesForVoice: str];
    return [dict objectForKey: NSVoiceName];
}
```

I can't figure the reason of this exception, since voices is allocated in the init method.
With gdb if I try to print the value of row when the exception is thrown, it prints zero, so I really don't know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Didn't you get a bunch of compiler errors with this code?  I copied and pasted it into a project and it wouldn't compile until I removed everything except for "ss" and "voices" from the @private ivar declarations. Once I did that that, the program worked fine.

Comment: I found out what was causing the compiler warnings that I mentioned in my last comment -- I was using ARC instead of garbage collection.  But when I switched to GC, the code you posted worked fine for me with no alterations.

Comment: Good find. Probably Ramy didn't set the project for either ARC or GC. In that cases, `voices` points to an array that was deallocated because nothing kept ownership of it.

Comment: I added a [voices retain] and it works perfectly, but I haven't understood the reason of this issue.I usually don't retain objects, in a CLI application I just use them if I haven't allocated them explicitly, and they're added to the autorelease pool.Can someone explain why I had to retain voices?